# Google Firestore and PHP integration

Tags: php, composer-php, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to connect my PHP script to read/write data from my local machine (for now) to my Firestore database. I have read the google documentation on that and trying to do so but getting error when I run the composer ommd=nd ... **composer require google/cloud-firestore**

[image]

Has anyone faced this issue before?

Answer (score 1):

You're installing dependency of `google/cloud-firestore` which requires grpc-extension and you can install with the help of [this](https://cloud.google.com/php/grpc).

If you don't want to install `grpc` and still want to use Firestore then probably [this package](https://github.com/ahsankhatri/firestore-php) is what you're looking for.